# How to represent an Sqlite3 database table using PyQt4 GUI

Tags: python, qt, sqlite, user-interface, pyqt4

I am working on a simple business organiser application that handles a database using sqlite, I have managed to represent the data from the table using a graph (matplotlib module) but I am now trying to figure out a way to represent the table on a GUI in a table format (much like a normal DB reader). I am using Python hence why the question is regarding PyQt.

I have tried to look for help around the internet but only helpful thing I could find was with QT in C++ which wasn't much help.

I am guessing that I will need to create a new window in QTDesigner and add a QTableWidget, but I have no clue on what to do after this.

Could anyone give me some advice on how do I achieve my objective.

Thanks!

Comment: [PyQt - Database Handling](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_database_handling.htm).

Comment: All the "official" Qt examples have been translated to Python but they are hard to find. Download the [PyQt source package](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5), unzip it and look in the `examples` directory. There you should be able to find examples on how to use the `QTableWidget` or `QTableView`